# How to fix an empty .csv file export from vb.net using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im trying to export a data table to a .csv file in vb.net Ive written code that opens a save file dialogue and successfully saves the .csv file but the file is 0 bytes and contains no data. I'm using MySQL database, the database name is "tickedoff" and the table that i want to export is "pet".
If anyone can see a mistake in my code and help me it would be greatly appreciated.. I am totally stumped at the moment.

This code is in Form1 (button click event):

```vb
Private Sub btnPetInfoExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPetInfoExport.Click
    Dim saveFileDialog1 = New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim statement As String = "SELECT pet.petID, pet.petName, pet.species, pet.breed, " _
                              & "pet.DOB, pet.gender, pet.weight," _
                              & "CONCAT(customer.lastName, ', ', customer.firstName) AS Customer " _
                              & "FROM pet INNER JOIN customer ON pet.customerID = customer.customerID " _
                              & "ORDER BY pet.petID"
    Dim petDataTable As DataTable =
            DataAccessLayer.GetPetDataTableForExport(statement)
    Dim saveFile As StreamWriter
    Dim fileName As String = String.Empty
    Dim csvBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    For i = 0 To petDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
        csvBuilder.Append(petDataTable.Columns(i).ColumnName + ","c)
    Next
    csvBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    For i = 0 To petDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
        For o = 0 To petDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
            csvBuilder.Append(petDataTable.Rows(i)(o).ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ","c)
        Next
        csvBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files ( .csv)|.csv|ALL files (.)|. "
    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName
        Try
            saveFile = File.CreateText(fileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

This function is called from the above sub and is in a separate class called "data access layer":

```vb
Public Shared Function GetPetDataTableForExport(statement As String) As 
    DataTable
    Dim petDataTableCommand As New MySqlCommand(statement)
    Dim petDataTable As New DataTable()
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Port=3306; database=tickedoff; username=root;")
    Dim petDataTableAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    petDataTableCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    petDataTableCommand.Connection = connection
    Try
        connection.Open()
        petDataTableAdapter.SelectCommand = petDataTableCommand
        'fill the table with the pet data from the database
        petDataTableAdapter.Fill(petDataTable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        petDataTableAdapter.Dispose()
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return petDataTable
End Function
```

Comment: I have formatted your code the way it should have been done.  Please format code properly in future, for readability.

Comment: You should get rid of that `Catch` block.  If you have a `Finally` block then you don't have to include a `Catch` block and yours does nothing useful so get rid of it. If you ever do want to rethrow an exception in a `Catch` block, NEVER use `Throw ex` because that truncates the stack trace and makes it appear the exception was thrown originally right there. ALWAYS just use `Throw`.

Comment: Firstly, did you bother checking whether there is any data in the `DataTable`? If not, why not? If so, why aren't you telling us the result? If there is no data and there's no exception thrown in that code then it should be obvious that your query produces an empty result set. You haven't shown us the query so how can we possibly tell you if something is wrong with it? If there is data in the `DataTable` then the code you've posted is completely irrelevant and the issue must be in the code that writes the data to a file but you haven't shown us that. All up, this is a rather poor question.

Comment: The fact that you have no badges indicates that you ignored the prompt to tour this site when you registered, so it's no big surprise that you would post a bad question.  That's why you are prompted to learn how the site works: to avoid wasting your time and ours on bad questions.  You should, at a minimum, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok thanks, first time posting but I will make sure of that in the future, so where did the other half of my code go when you "formatted" it?

Comment: Well the query was in the second block of code..........

Comment: Which is gone now.. thanks for that

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have to support OP that it looks like your edit did in fact lose some code. Please review.

Comment: I believe I have restored the missing code. My apologies for that. I made the mistake in part because the completely unformatted code was difficult to distinguish from the rest of the text, which is exactly why code should be formatted. We all make mistakes when we start out, myself included, but that's why we should make use of the information available, so as to minimise those mistakes. Anyway, enough of that.

Comment: The question still stands though: have you checked that the `DataTable` actually contains data? If not, that's the obvious issue. If so, step through the code that is supposed to traverse the data and write it to the file and see whether it does what you expect it to. Reading code is a first step but, if you don't see anything obvious, the immediate next step is to debug, i.e. set a breakpoint, step through the code and examine the state at each relevant step. Many times, issues become blindingly obvious when you do that because you what is rather than what you expect to be.